# Cheapest/easiest way to store/read 1 bit of data in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Problem is as title reads. What is the best way to do this? Currently I'm using dynamodb but I'm not convinced it's the cheapest due to how read capacity units are calculated (1kb minimum). If you had to store 1 bit of data and query it from a static website (hosted from S3), how would you do it?

Comment: You haven't indicated how often it's going to be read but, for pure storage, perhaps S3 One Zone-IA.

Comment: Ah good point. Read no more than 10 times a second (probably more like 5 at max). I tried S3 at first, but the timing is not fast enough for me. Sometimes it takes 2 or 3 minutes to get the most recent data.

Comment: Is it just one number you are storing, or do you have LOTS of such numbers? How reliable to you need it to be (for example, if it was kept in memory of ElastiCache but the instance might fail)?

Answer (score 0):

Thinking outside the box, some options would be:

- **Amazon ElastiCache** `cache.t2.micro` ($0.017 per hour)
- Roll-your-own cache on an **Amazon EC2** instance `t3.nano` ($0.0052 per hour)
- Store it in an **AWS IoT Shadow** ($2.25 per million messages)
- **DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX)** ($0.04 per hour)
- **AWS Systems Manager - Parameter Store** (Free) but might not be suitable